# Is it possible to use multiple baseurl in retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to use two server url using retrofit, but only one is working when I am using two base url. Please tell me how to use two base url in android.

```
public class APIUtils {
    public static String Url1 = "http://10.0.13.46:19460";
    public static String Url12 = "http://freshcamera.herokuapp.com";


    public static SOService getSOService(String url) {
        return RetrofitClient.getClient(url1).create(SOService.class);
    }

}
```

SOService class

```
public interface SOService {


   //URL 2
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/api/user/LoginUser")
    Call<Login> Login(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password")String password, @Field("grant_type")String passwords);
}
```

SOService_AI class

```
public interface SOService_AI {


    //URL 1
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/finalresult1")
    Call<List<AIImageProcessing>> AiImageCheck(@Field("img_data") String imgdata, @Field("name")String imgName);


}
```

Comment: Yes, you can create two different `Service` instances. Where did you attempt to use `Url12`? Also, `url1` is not defined in this post.

Comment: official documentation: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-change-api-base-url-at-runtime-2

Answer (score 21, accepted):

if you are working two url then you create two retrofit object. because single retrofit object work on single url.
if you want to access two your make two retofit object like below code..

```
public class ApiClient {
private final static String BASE_URL = "https://simplifiedcoding.net/demos/";
private final static String BASE_URL2 = "http://freshcamera.herokuapp.com";

public static ApiClient apiClient;
private Retrofit retrofit = null;
private Retrofit retrofit2=null;

public static ApiClient getInstance() {
    if (apiClient == null) {
        apiClient = new ApiClient();
    }
    return apiClient;
}

//private static Retrofit storeRetrofit = null;

public Retrofit getClient() {
    return getClient(null);
}

public Retrofit getClient2() {
    return getClient2(null);
}


private Retrofit getClient(final Context context) {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    client.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    client.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();

            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();


    return retrofit;
}
private Retrofit getClient2(final Context context) {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    client.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    client.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();

            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL2)
            .client(client.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();


    return retrofit;
}
```

}

then after access like below code ..

```
        ApiClient.getInstance().getClient();
    ApiClient.getInstance().getClient2();
```

Comment: if possible without creating two clients?

Answer (score 33):

I guess what you need is **changing URL at runtime** to a completely different one.

For example, the following code will `override` the URL passed as `baseUrl` to *retrofit* object.

```java
@GET
public Call<ResponseBody> profilePicture(@Url String url);
```

---

**Note**: You can't add url param to `@GET` and `@POST`. The URL must be passed to `@Url`.

```java
// ERROR ( @Url cannot be used with @GET URL)
@GET("users") // or POST
public Call<Foo> getUsers(@Url String url);

// CORRECT
@GET
public Call<Foo> getUsers(@Url String fullUrl);
```

Checkout [this tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-use-dynamic-urls-for-requests) for further information.

Comment: How we can use with POST request? As am getting below error when using this.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Url cannot be used with POST URL (parameter #1)    for method

Comment: @MuhammadMaqsood Make sure you're not adding paramter to `POST`. (`POST('/users/')` is not acceptable. Just add `POST` and pass the complete url to the `url` annotation). Was I clear?

Comment: I solved my case with HTTP interceptors. I wanted to use multiple base URLs & POST request with a payload.

Comment: If answer needs edit or improvements, you're welcome to do so.

Answer (score 10):

with Kotlin its even easier

```
companion object {
    // init Retrofit base server instance
    val redditClient by lazy { ApiService.invoke(REDDIT_BASE_URL) }
    val stackClient by lazy { ApiService.invoke(STACK_BASE_URL) }

    private val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
        this.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    }

    operator fun invoke(baseUrl: String): ApiService {
        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
            /**addNetworkInterceptor(StethoInterceptor()) */
            addNetworkInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        }.build()

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(client)
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(ApiService::class.java)
    }
}
```

just pass the baseUrl in the invoke method

Answer (score 5):

This is really easy now
Simply use Post or Get without a constant url instead accept it in a parameter and annotate that parameter with @Url

```
@GET
suspend fun handshakeUser(@Url url : String): Response<JsonObject>


@POST
suspend fun makePostRequest(
    @Header("Authorization") token: String = getToken(),
    @Url url: String,
    @Body inputModel: JsonObject
): Response<JsonObject>
```